# Thymeleaf v2.0.15 SaxParse Exception - Scanner state not 24

Tags: saxparseexception, thymeleaf

I am trying to use Thymeleaf template engine for generating Emails in my Spring Web Application. 
I have followed the documentation on their website, but I keep getting a SaxParseException no matter how simple my HTML5 template is.
I am using a HTML 5 template as shown below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
   <head>
        <title th:remove="all">Account confirmation HTML email</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3 th:utext="#{mail.template.confirmation.greeting(${user.firstName}, ${user.lastName})}"></h3>
        <p th:utext="#{mail.template.confirmation.introduction(${createdDate})}">
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

My Spring config.

```
@Bean
public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver() {
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver cltr = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    cltr.setPrefix("/dk/rfit/orderit/web/mail/");
    cltr.setSuffix(".html");
    cltr.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    cltr.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    cltr.setOrder(3);
    cltr.setCacheable(true);
    return cltr;
}

@Bean
public TemplateEngine mailTemplateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine ste = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    ste.setTemplateResolver(emailTemplateResolver());
    return ste;
}
```

StackTrace..

```
2013-01-31 08:01:33,431 [org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine] [http-bio-8080-exec-10] (TemplateEngine.java:829) INFO  org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine  - [THYMELEAF] INITIALIZING TEMPLATE ENGINE
2013-01-31 08:01:33,496 [org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.AbstractTemplateResolver] [http-bio-8080-exec-10] (AbstractTemplateResolver.java:99) INFO  org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.AbstractTemplateResolver  - [THYMELEAF] INITIALIZING TEMPLATE RESOLVER: org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver
2013-01-31 08:01:33,496 [org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.AbstractTemplateResolver] [http-bio-8080-exec-10] (AbstractTemplateResolver.java:110) INFO  org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.AbstractTemplateResolver  - [THYMELEAF] TEMPLATE RESOLVER INITIALIZED OK
2013-01-31 08:01:33,498 [org.thymeleaf.messageresolver.AbstractMessageResolver] [http-bio-8080-exec-10] (AbstractMessageResolver.java:72) INFO  org.thymeleaf.messageresolver.AbstractMessageResolver  - [THYMELEAF] INITIALIZING MESSAGE RESOLVER: org.thymeleaf.spring3.messageresolver.SpringMessageResolver
2013-01-31 08:01:33,499 [org.thymeleaf.messageresolver.AbstractMessageResolver] [http-bio-8080-exec-10] (AbstractMessageResolver.java:78) INFO  org.thymeleaf.messageresolver.AbstractMessageResolver  - [THYMELEAF] MESSAGE RESOLVER INITIALIZED OK
2013-01-31 08:01:33,506 [org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.CONFIG] [http-bio-8080-exec-10] (ConfigurationPrinterHelper.java:130) INFO  org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.CONFIG  - [THYMELEAF]     TEMPLATE ENGINE CONFIGURATION:
[THYMELEAF] * Cache Factory implementation: org.thymeleaf.cache.StandardCacheManager
[THYMELEAF] * Template modes:
[THYMELEAF]     * LEGACYHTML5
[THYMELEAF]     * VALIDXHTML
[THYMELEAF]     * HTML5
[THYMELEAF]     * XHTML
[THYMELEAF]     * XML
[THYMELEAF]     * VALIDXML
[THYMELEAF] * Template resolvers (in order):
[THYMELEAF]     * [3] org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver
[THYMELEAF] * Message resolvers (in order):
[THYMELEAF]     * org.thymeleaf.spring3.messageresolver.SpringMessageResolver
[THYMELEAF] * Dialect: org.thymeleaf.spring3.dialect.SpringStandardDialect
[THYMELEAF]     * Prefix: "th"
[THYMELEAF] TEMPLATE ENGINE CONFIGURED OK
2013-01-31 08:01:33,507 [org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine] [http-bio-8080-exec-10] (TemplateEngine.java:842) INFO  org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine  - [THYMELEAF] TEMPLATE ENGINE INITIALIZED
2013-01-31 08:09:52,146 [org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine] [http-bio-8080-exec-10] (TemplateEngine.java:1173) ERROR org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine  - [THYMELEAF][http-bio-8080-exec-10] Exception processing template "account-confirmation": Exception parsing document
2013-01-31 08:09:52,149 [dk.rfit.orderit.web.controller.AccountController] [http-bio-8080- exec-10] (AccountController.java:213) ERROR dk.rfit.orderit.web.controller.AccountController       org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.parseTemplateUsingP     ool(AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:167)       org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.parseTemplate(Abstr actNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:115)
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:276)
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1192)
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1148)
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1095)
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1008)
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:982)



dk.rfit.orderit.web.service.EmailServiceThymeLeafImpl$1.prepare(EmailServiceThymeLeafImpl.java:65)
        at       org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:352)
        ... 73 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Scanner State 24 not Recognized 
        at     com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1245    )
        at     com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:5    22)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
        at       org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.doParse(AbstractNon        ValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:208)
        at          org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.parseTemplateUsingP        ool(AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:132)
        ... 82 more
```

Hope that somebody can tell me what to do to solve this problem..

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Vel's answer: if you need to insert invalid XHTML via utext, which could be perfectly fine for HTML5 (like unclosed <br> tags), you need to use template mode LEGACYHTML5:

```
cltr.setTemplateMode("LEGACYHTML5");
```

Comment: Hi. I am getting similar exception. 
` Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/proj] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Exception parsing document] with root cause

org.xml.sax.SAXException: Scanner State 24 not Recognized 
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1253)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:648)`

Is there any tool to check/validate the HTML is well formed.

Comment: My application is using HTML5 + Thymeleaf

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually raised by the parser when the parsed markup is not well-formed XML.
The html5 template file becomes not a valid html file after parsing. This means some end-tag (/>)or something extra tag which does not meet the validation of XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to specify property in `application.properties`:

```
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
```

Having `nekohtml` dependency in your project, e.g. in a `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
    <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

is mandatory.